# Остановить отправку формы

Tags: javascript

Есть **input**  `<input id="send" type="submit" name="refresh">` , как сделать на нажатие проверку условия, и в зависимости от него отправлять либо не отправлять форму.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
     $("#send").click(function(e){
        if ($valid) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("Ошибка");
        return false;
       } else $("#form").submit({name = refresh},function (){
                alert('success!');
              });
        })
});
```

В итоге выводится ошибка, но форма всё равно отправляется и без параметра **name** В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вместо `type="submit"`, поставьте `type="button"`.
Скрипт вызывайте следующим методом:

```js
$('input#send').on('click', function (){
  // e.preventDefault() - для нормальных браузеров
  // evt.preventDefault() - FireFox
  var formData = $('form#data').serialize();
    if (formData){
      $.post(url, formData, function(resp){
        // Обработка ответа
      });
    }
});
```

Делайте сериализацию Вашей формы для отправки даных куда-то. После чего - делайте обработку событий и ответа от сервера. Делайте обработку кодов ошибки.

Answer (score 2):

Проверку нужно ставить в обработчик onsubmit формы, где возвращать false/true

$("#form").onsubmit

Answer (score 0):

Я так же столкнулся с проблемой,когда нельзя было взять и просто дизейбл навесить. А кнопка по-умолчанию должна была быть submit,а не button. Вот решение

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('form').on('submit', function() {
                $('.btn-create').prop({
                    'value' : 'Подождите...',
                    'type' : 'button',
                    'disabled' : true
                });
            });
        });
```